# rosdep is used to install system and package dependencies (in a workspace)

Tags: ros, rosdep, dependencies, package, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep),

> rosdep is a command-line tool for installing system dependencies.

In the same documentation article, it is stated that `rosdep` can also be used to *install dependencies of all packages in the workspace*.

First of all, what is a system dependency? What isn't a system dependency? Can `rosdep` both be used to install system dependencies and package dependencies?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287527/rosdep-is-used-to-install-system-and-package-dependencies-(in-a-workspace)/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> First of all, what is a system dependency?

Anything (ie: library or other installable artefact) not a ROS package.

> What isn't a system dependency?

Anything that is a ROS package (ie: has a package manifest and a build script that uses Catkin).

> Can `rosdep` both be used to install system dependencies and package dependencies?

Yes. It does this by default.

With a workspace containing ROS packages and the following invocation:

```
rosdep install --ignore-packages-from-source --from-paths $CATKIN_WS/src
```

`rosdep` will check for all package manifests what the build and run depends are, whether those are ROS packages or not, if they are, whether they are present in the workspace, and all dependencies that are left (both ROS pkgs and system dependencies) are then installed using the platform's package manager (see #q215059).

---

Edit:

> I can install a ROS package only using `rosdep`, right? Or can I also use another tool (e.g. `apt`)?

I would say that the typical way to install ROS packages (on Ubuntu and Debian at least) would/should be using `apt` (it is also used in the official [installation tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation-1)). That is, if you know that the package is released for a specific ROS version and OS. Personally I only use `rosdep` to install dependencies (whether system or regular ROS pkg) for packages in my catkin workspace. For packages that you install using `apt`, using `rosdep` makes no sense as `apt` will already install all dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-04**:
I can install a ROS package only using `rosdep`, right? Or can I also use another tool (e.g. `apt`)?

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-04**:
What do you mean by "regular ROS"?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-05**:
I left off a word: it should have read "regular ROS package".

Fixed.